# How does AngularJS knows where to look for a module to load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app module defining dependencies (taken from `phonecat`-Tutorial) in the directory `app`:

```
app.module.js:
angular.module('phonecatApp', [
    'phoneList'                          // (*)
]);
```

Then, in a directory `app/phone-list` are the module:

```
phone-list/phone-list.module.js:
angular.module('phoneList', []);
```

and component:

```
phone-list/phone-list.component.js:
angular.module('phoneList').component('phoneList', {...});
```

From registering the module `phoneList` in the first snippet at `(*)`, how does AngularJS knows where to fetch the module from? Is the mapping from `phoneList` to `phone-list`-directory naming a builtin feature?

Comment: The relevant modules have to be included in scripts included in the page. This is either done by manually adding various script tags or by task runners like grunt, gulp, webpack etc. If dependency module code doesn't exist angular will throw error

Comment: In simpler terms...where the code comes from is not angular's responsibility. It has to already exist for angular to work

Comment: I would accept this as the accepted answer because it's what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for relevant modules has to be included in scripts included in the page. This is either done by manually adding various script tags or by task runners like grunt, gulp, webpack etc adding them for you.

If dependency module code doesn't exist angular will throw error

In simpler terms -  where the code comes from is not angular's responsibility. It has to already exist for angular to work

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS has a dictionnary of modules. The key in this dictionnary is the string that you give your module when you register it with the following line :

```
angular.module('phoneList', []);
```

That's why the previous line must always have been executed in javascript before you can use your module by adding a component (like following line) :

```
angular.module('phoneList').component('phoneList', {...});
```

or by injecting your module into another module

```
angular.module('phonecatApp', [
    'phoneList'
]);
```